# select rows with the same value using Codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to select all with the same  value using codeigniter.

```
    +-------+-------------+------------+
    | id    | coupon_code | Barcode    |
    +-------+-------------+------------+
    | 1     | COUPON02    | 12542      |   
    | 2     | COUPON02    | 11229      | 
    | 3     | COUPON03    | 11823      | 
    | 4     | COUPON03    | 47875      | 
    +-------+-----------+--------------+

   public  function fetch_available_coupon(){

    $coupon_code = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('barcode');
    $this->db->where('coupon_code', $coupon_code);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return   $data;
    }else{
        return false;        
    }
 }
```

in my result it only show 1 row not the not all the same Coupon_Code

Im using codeigniter as my active record. Please Help thank you

Comment: how u get data ? r u using return method?

Comment: What is expected result when passing coupon_code COUPON02?

Comment: Remove `$coupon_code` from `$this->db->group_by('coupon_code', $coupon_code);` Just use `$this->db->group_by('coupon_code');`

Comment: @Maninderpreet Singh yes im using return

Comment: as saty said remove `$coupon_code` from group_by method

Comment: @coolshox post your full code!!

Comment: @Saty i need this variable $coupon_code because i need make this query dynamic.

Comment: Also check column name it is `coupon_code` OR `Coupon_Code`

Comment: Use where condition for it as `$this->db->where('coupon_code', $coupon_code);`

Answer (score 3):

use where condition instead of group by

```
 $this->db->where('coupon_code', $coupon_code);
```

You can use GROUP BY to group values from a column, and, if you wish, perform calculations on that column. You can use COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc., functions on the grouped column.